# How to style material UI box component to overlay

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm really new when it comes to styling components and making them look the way I want.

My desired outcome is to have two box components that overlap each other for a nice clean look for displaying user stats and remaining targets for the day.

What I have in mind is:

[image]

If anyone can give me some pointers with regards to styling the box component to look like the above image, I would be really greatful.

Answer (score 0):

To start please take a look at [MUI Box](https://mui.com/components/box/), which provides a great description to play with the Box component of Material-UI.

Here is an example from the link

```
<Box
  sx={{
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
      opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
    },
  }}
/>
```

**sx** is being used for styling the Box component and inside this example we can see that we can change the width, height and background color of the box from the component itself. To something similar to what you had requested I took the liberty of using styled-components to style the Box component as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import styled from "styled-components";

const DataBoxContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 20vh;
  position: relative;
`;

const StyledOuterBox = styled(Box)`
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
`;

const StyledInnerBox = styled(Box)`
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
`;

const StyledData = styled.p`
  color: black;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin-inline-start: 20px;
`;

export default function DataBox() {
  return (
    <DataBoxContainer>
      <StyledOuterBox
        sx={{
          width: 500,
          height: 250,
          backgroundColor: "gray"
        }}
      >
        <StyledData>test</StyledData>
      </StyledOuterBox>
      <StyledInnerBox
        sx={{
          width: 480,
          height: 200,
          backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}
      />
    </DataBoxContainer>
  );
}
```

Feel free to play with this example at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-mountain-k8qxf?file=/src/components/DataBox.jsx:0-1038)
I'm sure this can be improved but can give you an idea on how to start.
Please feel free to ask me any questions on it, as you requested for pointers but I have provided a code.